# apache server can't start because of phpmyadmin.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm trying to start apache2 server but it complains at phpmyadmin.conf

[image]

File phpmyadmin.conf looks so:

[image]

It looks ok for me, but perhaps I miss something.

This error appeared after I tried to change default location of website  doing commands as  a2dissite,a2ensite.
My apache.conf  file looks so http://paste.org.ru/?ingbp6

Help! Thanks.

Comment: Does PHP work elsewhere? Can you get a `phpinfo()` printed out from any page?

Comment: yes, fortunately or unfortunately it works - http://paste.org.ru/?ec2097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `apache-php` module missing or being turned off. Try this:

```
aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
ln -s ../mods-available/php5.conf ./php5.conf
ln -s ../mods-available/php5.load ./php5.load
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: thanks for advice! I did it http://paste.org.ru/?6u5dcx and got a new error...     secure.conf file looks so http://paste.org.ru/?7xzjwh

Comment: Comment the line out like this: `#Action php-cgi /php-bin/php`

Comment: helped! it works! thanks. Is it not bad just to comment  this line?

Comment: The line does not work due to another `mod_action` plugin being disabled. You can enable the line once you have `mod_action` enabled.